# Google RPC authentication with trusted credentials

Tags: c#, authentication, grpc

There is an example in gRPC:

```
Channel channel = new Channel("127.0.0.1:30051", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
```

it works. Now I would like to authenticate the user on server either using the login / password pair or using Windows trusted authentication.
The authentication documentation https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/ shows some examples:

- either with some PEM certificate that has nothing to do with windows account
- or with a "trusted" authentication, but not in the meaning that one Windows computer trusts to the other Windows. The meaning is that credentials are trusted with Google.

Is it possible to do Windows-trusted authentication between two Windows PCs using gRPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe client-side SSL is what you are looking for: https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/#using-client-side-ssltls

You want to authenticate both ends of the connection. This won't be a simple task, since you have to manage and update certificates in clusters.

If what you are looking for is Windows account specific integration, I don't think gRPC is providing one today. You may post a feature request to https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues.